# preemptions due to malloc

Tags: linux, malloc

I am thinking of the following scenario and I want to double check it with you.

One Linux process with 2 or more threads running in parallel on different cores. Let's say that they both call malloc with same amount such that malloc will not have to invoke mmap. In other words, the heap is big enough and (previously) increased by other sbrk invocations. In a such case, the memory allocations are entirely in user-space. By looking on git hub I have seen that there is a mutex protecting the internal data structures that malloc uses.

My questions is, can a thread be preempted out by the kernel given that the threads try to acquire the same lock? In other words, one of the threads will suffer a penalty in its execution due to the fact that the other has got that lock.

Thanks,

Comment: Mutexes usually spin before they put their thread to sleep. If thread B finishes quick, before A hits the sleep part, A will acquire the mutex and there won't a scheduler penalty due to the mutex.

Comment: I was thinking of a such a case. Is there any way to know how much that malloc mutex will spin until hitting the sleep part?

Do you know of any malloc option that can do that ?

Comment: Read the source code of your pthread library. Musl does 100 spins. If you want more, then I suppose you can always loop on pthread_mutex_trylock a bit.

Comment: So when the malloc mutex finishes spinning the other thread can go to sleep. This means that the other thread will be preempted out due to a malloc call ... right ?

Comment: `int spinning_mutex_lock(mutex_t *Mx){ for(int i=0;i<NSPINS;i++){ if(SUCCESS==try_lock(Mx) return SUCCESS;  } lock_the_mutex_now_or_sleep_until_i_locked_it(Mx); }`